# Как называется "фигура" в домино?

Tags: одним-словом

Как называется одна отдельно взятая плоская штуковина, фишка, в домино? Т.е. как правильно назвать одну доминошку?

Comment: Если заглянуть (даже) в Wiki, по слову домино, мы найдем `кость, костяшка`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Она называется "костяшка" (см. второе значение на сайте [gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EA%EE%F1%F2%FF%F8%EA%E0))

Comment: Некоторые пенсионеры, которые играют в домино во дворах, называют её «камень», я сам слышал.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то именно она, эта ***костяшка***, "домино" и называется. А название игры исходно было множественное число от этого "домино". Но поскольку домино несклоняемо (множественное число по форме совпадает с единственным), саму игру стали называть домино - в единственном числе, а "доминошки" - костями, костяшками, пластинками и проч.

Кстати, в других языках этот принцип сохранился. В английском - игра dominos (также - dominoes), коcтяшки - domino, множественное - domonos

Answer (score 3):

Есть ещё разговорное слово [`доминошка`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is called камень by the players.

Comment: Maybe `Костяшка`